# How does group by works in sequelize?

Tags: javascript, sql, orm, sequelize.js, query-builder

I am looking for `group by` queries through Sequelize and cannot seem to find any documentation.

```sql
    SELECT column, count(column)  
    FROM table 
    GROUP BY column
```

Comment: although it can group it cannot execute the above. I am using a raw query now

Answer (score 81, accepted):

issue: https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/348

```
User.findAll({
 group: ['field']
})
```

i use sequelize@2.0.0-dev9

Answer (score 52):

I think you looking for something like this:

```
 Table.findAll({
   attributes: ['column1', 
     sequelize.fn('count', sequelize.col('column2'))], 
   group: ["Table.column1"]
 }).success(function (result) { });
```

**Update:** Newer versions of Sequelize uses **.then** instead of **.success**.

```
 Table.findAll({
   attributes: ['column1', 
     sequelize.fn('count', sequelize.col('column2'))], 
   group: ["Table.column1"]
 }).then(function (result) { });
```

Comment: Wow, this is great. How did you know that?

Comment: Newer versions of sequelize now use `.then(function (result) { });` instead of  `.success(function (result) { });`

Comment: is there any documentation on this?

Comment: @Ante http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/models-usage/#manipulating-the-dataset-with-limit-offset-order-and-group

Comment: @mparnisari sorry, I missed this part "Everything you see below can also be done for group"

Comment: No worries. @user964287 this should be marked as the correct answer!

Comment: Awesome answer is awesome. I've been struggling a bit with sequelize's documentation. This was of much help.

Answer (score 18):

Group by with count `sequelize ORM`

`'field'` - custom user input, you can rename this string, it's your `field(column)` in database

`'count'` - reserved sequelize keyword string need for get `count` in `sequelize`

`'cnt'` - custom user input, you can rename this string, it's your output `count`

Sequelize version `3.25.0`

```
User.findAll({
      attributes: ['field', [sequelize.fn('count', sequelize.col('field')), 'cnt']],
      group: ['field'],
})
```

Answer (score 6):

Try this -

```
Table.count(
{
   attributes: ['column'], 
   group: 'column',
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Example: how to add an convenient alias to the grouped function column.

I did this as a separate response mostly because it wouldn't format well in a comment...  otherwise I would have just added it to Sampat's answer.

```
function getSumsBySomeId() {
  const criteria = {
    attributes: ['some_id', [sequelize.fn('sum', sequelize.col('some_count')), 'some_count_sum']],
    group: ['some_id'],
    raw: true
  };
  return Table.getAll(criteria);
}
```

YIELDS:

```
{ some_id: 42, some_count_sum: 100 },
{ some_id: 43, some_count_sum: 150 }
...
etc.
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code should look something like these using ES6 standard.

```
Table.findAll({ attributes: ['column1', sequelize.fn('count', sequelize.col('column2'))],   group: ["Table.column1"]  }).then( (result) => { })
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try this*

```
Table.findAll({
     group: ['column']
})
```

Comment: Meaningless SQL query

Comment: That is what's on their documentation, I wouldn't be on stackoverflow looking for answers if that example is useful enough. Right really useless.

Answer (score 1):

**You need to use `row.get('count')` to get the count, `row.count` won't work**

The API mentioned at [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23107848/895245) is correct, but there were a few tricks I was missing in order to actually get the `count` results out.

As mentioned at: [How do I select a column using an alias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32649218/how-do-i-select-a-column-using-an-alias/69890944#69890944) you need to use `.get()` for `attribute` aliased columns for some reason.

And another thing: you need to use `parseInt` to get an integer out of PostgreSQL `count`: [Postgres sequelize raw query to get count returns string value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47843370/postgres-sequelize-raw-query-to-get-count-returns-string-value) due to bigint shenanigans.

Minimal runnable example also demonstrating `ORDER BY`, `WHERE` and `HAVING`:

main.js

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
// https://cirosantilli.com/sequelize-example
const assert = require('assert')
const { DataTypes, Op } = require('sequelize')
const common = require('./common')
const sequelize = common.sequelize(__filename, process.argv[2])
;(async () => {
const UserLikesPost = sequelize.define('UserLikesPost', {
  userId: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
  },
  postId: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
  },
}, {})
await UserLikesPost.sync({force: true})
await UserLikesPost.create({userId: 1, postId: 1})
await UserLikesPost.create({userId: 1, postId: 2})
await UserLikesPost.create({userId: 1, postId: 3})
await UserLikesPost.create({userId: 2, postId: 1})
await UserLikesPost.create({userId: 2, postId: 2})
await UserLikesPost.create({userId: 3, postId: 1})
await UserLikesPost.create({userId: 4, postId: 1})
// Count likes on all posts but:
// - don't consider likes userId 4
// - only return posts that have at least 2 likes
// Order posts by those with most likes first.
const postLikeCounts = await UserLikesPost.findAll({
  attributes: [
    'postId',
    [sequelize.fn('COUNT', '*'), 'count'],
  ],
  group: ['postId'],
  where: { userId: { [Op.ne]: 4 }},
  order: [[sequelize.col('count'), 'DESC']],
  having: sequelize.where(sequelize.fn('COUNT', '*'), Op.gte, 2)
})
assert.strictEqual(postLikeCounts[0].postId, 1)
assert.strictEqual(parseInt(postLikeCounts[0].get('count'), 10), 3)
assert.strictEqual(postLikeCounts[1].postId, 2)
assert.strictEqual(parseInt(postLikeCounts[1].get('count'), 10), 2)
assert.strictEqual(postLikeCounts.length, 2)
await sequelize.close()
})()
```

common.js

```
const path = require('path');

const { Sequelize } = require('sequelize');

function sequelize(filename, dialect, opts) {
  if (dialect === undefined) {
    dialect = 'l'
  }
  if (dialect === 'l') {
    return new Sequelize(Object.assign({
      dialect: 'sqlite',
      storage: path.parse(filename).name + '.sqlite'
    }, opts));
  } else if (dialect === 'p') {
    return new Sequelize('tmp', undefined, undefined, Object.assign({
      dialect: 'postgres',
      host: '/var/run/postgresql',
    }, opts));
  } else {
    throw new Error('Unknown dialect')
  }
}
exports.sequelize = sequelize
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "tmp",
  "private": true,
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "pg": "8.5.1",
    "pg-hstore": "2.3.3",
    "sequelize": "6.5.1",
    "sqlite3": "5.0.2"
  }
}
```

and PostgreSQL 13.4 on Ubuntu 21.10. [GitHub upstream](https://github.com/cirosantilli/cirosantilli.github.io/blob/b32ad80de1a6c7e5ab414e0472062d67696c7f2e/sequelize/count.js).

Generated PostgreSQL query:

```
SELECT
  "postId",
  COUNT('*') AS "count"
FROM
  "UserLikesPosts" AS "UserLikesPost"
WHERE
  "UserLikesPost"."userId" != 4
GROUP BY
  "postId"
HAVING
  COUNT('*') >= 2
ORDER BY
  "count" DESC;
```

**`JOIN` + `GROUP BY` + aggregate**

See: [Sequelize query with count in inner join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42470383/sequelize-query-with-count-in-inner-join/69904521#69904521)

Answer (score 0):

To create a query like

```
SELECT key, COUNT(ref) FROM MyModel GROUP BY key
```

You can do this as follows

```
  const results = await MyModel.findAll({
    attributes: ['key', [Sequelize.fn('COUNT', Sequelize.col('ref')), 'count']],
    group: ['key']
  });
```

Optionally you can cast the result to something like `(MyModel & { count: number })[]`

Finally, to extract the count for each row, you'll need to use the `getDataValue` function. e.g.

```
results.map(r => r.getDataValue('count'))
```