# Sequelize query with count in inner join

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

I am trying to convert this query to sequelize query object what is the right wayto do it?

```
SELECT families.id, count('answers.familyId') FROM families LEFT JOIN 
answers on families.id = answers.familyId WHERE answers.isActive=1 AND
answers.answer=1 GROUP BY families.id HAVING COUNT('answers.familyId')>=6
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Let's assume that `Family` is your `families` sequelize model and `Answer` is your `answers` sequelize model, and `sequelize` is your Sequelize instance

```js
Family.findAll({
    attributes: ['*', sequelize.fn('COUNT', sequelize.col('Answers.familyId'))],
    include: [
        {
            model: Answer,
            attributes: [],
            where: {
                isActive: 1,
                answer: 1
            }
        }
    ],
    group: '"Family.id"',
    having: sequelize.where(sequelize.fn('COUNT', sequelize.col('Answers.familyId')), '>=', 6)
}).then((families) => {
    // result
});
```

Useful documentation links:

- [**`sequelize.fn()`**](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/api/sequelize/#fnfn-args-sequelizefn)
- [**`sequelize.where()`**](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/api/sequelize/#whereattr-comparator-logic-sequelizewhere)
- [**`sequelize.col()`**](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/api/sequelize/#colcol-sequelizecol)

Answer (score 3):

**You need to use `get()` on the `attribute:` aliased `count` column**

There are two important gotchas when reading the aggregates out:

- the `count` only shows up on results if you alias it with `attributes` as shown by Piotr at https://stackoverflow.com/a/42472696/895245 and as shown at [How do I select a column using an alias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32649218/how-do-i-select-a-column-using-an-alias/69890944#69890944) `attributes` aliasing has the unexpected effect of requiring you to use `.get()`.
- as mentioned at: [How does group by works in sequelize?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22627258/how-does-group-by-works-in-sequelize/69896449#69896449) the `count` comes out as a string in PostgreSQL due to bigint shenanigans, and you need `parseInt` it

Here's a minimal runnable example where we have posts and users who can like posts, and we want to count how:

- how many likes each user has
- ignoring likes to post2
- considering only users that have 0 or 1 likes in total

The following small improvements are made over Piotr's code:

- you likely don't want  `attributes: ['*'` because that selects all columns, and therefore generally includes columns that are neither aggregates nor grouped by, leading to indeterminate behavior in some DBMSs and errors in others. You should just specify the GROUP by column instead, in our case the column is `name`.
- using the slightly cleaner `Op.lte` rather than the literal `'<='`

Due to `required: false`, this first version does a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` + `COUNT(column)`, see also: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/174694/how-to-get-a-group-where-the-count-is-zero

sqlite.js

```
const assert = require('assert');
const { DataTypes, Op, Sequelize } = require('sequelize');
const sequelize = new Sequelize('tmp', undefined, undefined, Object.assign({
  dialect: 'sqlite',
  storage: 'tmp.sqlite'
}));
;(async () => {
const User = sequelize.define('User', {
  name: { type: DataTypes.STRING },
}, {});
const Post = sequelize.define('Post', {
  body: { type: DataTypes.STRING },
}, {});
User.belongsToMany(Post, {through: 'UserLikesPost'});
Post.belongsToMany(User, {through: 'UserLikesPost'});
await sequelize.sync({force: true});
const user0 = await User.create({name: 'user0'})
const user1 = await User.create({name: 'user1'})
const user2 = await User.create({name: 'user2'})
const post0 = await Post.create({body: 'post0'})
const post1 = await Post.create({body: 'post1'})
const post2 = await Post.create({body: 'post2'})
// Set likes for each user.
await user0.addPosts([post0, post1])
await user1.addPosts([post0, post2])

let rows = await User.findAll({
  attributes: [
    'name',
    [sequelize.fn('COUNT', sequelize.col('Posts.id')), 'count'],
  ],
  include: [
    {
      model: Post,
      attributes: [],
      required: false,
      through: {attributes: []},
      where: { id: { [Op.ne]: post2.id }},
    },
  ],
  group: ['User.name'],
  order: [[sequelize.col('count'), 'DESC']],
  having: sequelize.where(sequelize.fn('COUNT', sequelize.col('Posts.id')), Op.lte, 1)
})
assert.strictEqual(rows[0].name, 'user1')
assert.strictEqual(parseInt(rows[0].get('count'), 10), 1)
assert.strictEqual(rows[1].name, 'user2')
assert.strictEqual(parseInt(rows[1].get('count'), 10), 0)
assert.strictEqual(rows.length, 2)
})().finally(() => { return sequelize.close() });
```

with:

package.json

```
{
  "name": "tmp",
  "private": true,
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "pg": "8.5.1",
    "pg-hstore": "2.3.3",
    "sequelize": "6.5.1",
    "sqlite3": "5.0.2"
  }
}
```

and Node v14.17.0.

If we wanted the `INNER JOIN` version excluding 0 counts, we could just remove the `required: false`, which makes it be the default `true`. We can also use do a slightly simpler `COUNT(*)` since there will be no NULLs now:

```
let rows = await User.findAll({
  attributes: [
    'name',
    [sequelize.fn('COUNT', '*'), 'count'],
  ],
  include: [
    {
      model: Post,
      attributes: [],
      through: {attributes: []},
      where: { id: { [Op.ne]: post2.id }},
    },
  ],
  group: ['User.name'],
  order: [[sequelize.col('count'), 'DESC']],
  having: sequelize.where(sequelize.fn('COUNT', '*'), Op.lte, 1)
})
assert.strictEqual(rows[0].name, 'user1')
assert.strictEqual(parseInt(rows[0].get('count'), 10), 1)
assert.strictEqual(rows.length, 1)
```

**PostgreSQL support has been broken for several years due to `column X must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function`**

The above code should work for PostgreSQL too, but as mentioned at:

- https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/3256
- https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/5481#issuecomment-964387232

there's a bug and it doesn't. The fact that such glaring bugs have persisted for several years make me doubt if I should really be using this ORM.

The workaround is to use both:

```
  raw: true,
  includeIgnoreAttributes: false,
```

Full working example with the workaround:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
const assert = require('assert');
const { DataTypes, Op, Sequelize } = require('sequelize');
const sequelize = new Sequelize('tmp', undefined, undefined, Object.assign({
  dialect: 'postgres',
  host: '/var/run/postgresql',
}));
;(async () => {
const User = sequelize.define('User', {
  name: { type: DataTypes.STRING },
}, {});
const Post = sequelize.define('Post', {
  body: { type: DataTypes.STRING },
}, {});
User.belongsToMany(Post, {through: 'UserLikesPost'});
Post.belongsToMany(User, {through: 'UserLikesPost'});
await sequelize.sync({force: true});
const user0 = await User.create({name: 'user0'})
const user1 = await User.create({name: 'user1'})
const user2 = await User.create({name: 'user2'})
const post0 = await Post.create({body: 'post0'})
const post1 = await Post.create({body: 'post1'})
const post2 = await Post.create({body: 'post2'})
// Set likes for each user.
await user0.addPosts([post0, post1])
await user1.addPosts([post0, post2])

let rows = await User.findAll({
  attributes: [
    'name',
    [sequelize.fn('COUNT', '*'), 'count'],
  ],
  raw: true,
  includeIgnoreAttributes: false,
  include: [
    {
      model: Post,
      where: { id: { [Op.ne]: post2.id }},
    },
  ],
  group: ['User.name'],
  order: [[sequelize.col('count'), 'DESC']],
  having: sequelize.where(sequelize.fn('COUNT', '*'), Op.lte, 1)
})
assert.strictEqual(rows[0].name, 'user1')
assert.strictEqual(parseInt(rows[0].count, 10), 1)
assert.strictEqual(rows.length, 1)
})().finally(() => { return sequelize.close() });
```

tested on PostgreSQL 13.4, Ubuntu 21.10.

**Related**

[Counting associated entries with Sequelize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37817808/counting-associated-entries-with-sequelize)

Comment: Had a similar problem and using the `includeIgnoreAttributes` + `raw` helped me! Thank you so much fella!