# Postgres sequelize raw query to get count returns string value

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I am using postgresql sequelize in my node-express server.

When I run the following SQL Command, I am getting a string value for result.

I want to get *Integer* value for this count.

```
SELECT count(id) from collaborators where id<3
```

Result:

```
count =  [ { count: '1' } ]
```

Is there any way to get number values for result? Or do I always need to use *parseInt(count, 10)* to get int value?

I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 11):

[@DemtriOS](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5714855/demetrios) is correct that `count` returns `bigint` hence interpreted into `string`, you can directly typecast it directly on your query like so:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(id)::int
FROM collaborators
WHERE id < 3
```

Answer (score 4):

According to this https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/functions-aggregate.html, the count() function returns bigint type. Because of this it will get interpreted as a string.  It looks like explicit conversion to an int is what you will have to do.  So, `parseInt(count, 10)` it is.

Comment: Yuck. I don't like that at all.